# How do we check if the children exists for a given parent?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to iterate over all process and print their children like:

```
parent pid = 1
-------------- somename_1, pid = 2, state = 0
-------------- somename_2, pid = 3, state = 0
parent pid = 4
-------------- somename_3, pid = 5, state = 0
-------------- somename_4, pid = 6, state = 0
```

So far my code in the module looks like this. I don't want to print pid of the parent who have no children, so I am tying to check for existence of children using the if condition in the following code. The if condition does not seem to work for me. Any ideas?

```
static int my_read_proc(char *buf, char **start, off_t off, int count,
                    int *peof, void *data)
{
int len = 0;
struct task_struct *parent, *child_ptr;
struct list_head *child_runner;
for_each_process(parent){
    len += sprintf(buf+len, "parent pid = %d\n", parent->pid);
    list_for_each(child_runner, &parent->children){
        child_ptr = list_entry(child_runner, struct task_struct, sibling);
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "------------------ %s: pid = %d, state = %ld\n" , child_ptr->comm, child_ptr->pid, child_ptr->state);
    }
}
printk(KERN_INFO "%s", buf);
return  len;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with [`list_empty`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/list.h?id=refs/tags/v3.13#n186), if a process has any children

```
for_each_process(parent) {
    if (!list_empty(&parent->children)) {
    ...
    }
}
```